# How to avoid duplicates in XQuery results?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

This is newbie question.  I am just start learning XQuery and XPath recently.

Consider this XML

```
<employees>
  <employee empid="1">
    <ename>KING</ename>
    <mgr/>
    <hiredate>17-11-1981</hiredate>
  </employee>
  <employee empid="2">
    <ename>BLAKE</ename>
    <mgr>7839</mgr>
    <hiredate>1-5-1981</hiredate>
    <test>
      <sub1>one</sub1>
      <sub2>two</sub2>
    </test>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

When I execute the following XQuery,

```
let $db := db:open("example")
for $item1 in $db/employees/employee,
    $item2 in $db/employees/employee/test
return ($item1/mgr,$item1/ename,$item2/sub1)
```

I got...

```
<mgr/>
<ename>KING</ename>
<sub1>one</sub1>
<mgr>7839</mgr>
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<sub1>one</sub1>
```

The result that I am hoping to get is...

```
<mgr/>
<ename>KING</ename>
<mgr>7839</mgr>
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<sub1>one</sub1>
```

This is because sub1 only exist in /employee/@empid='2'.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?  Thanks

Comment: Your example XML data is broken – the `<employees>` element lacks the closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` expression

```
for $item1 in $db/employees/employee,
    $item2 in $db/employees/employee/test
```

`$item1` iterates through all the `employees/employee` elements, and `$item2` iterates through all the `employees/employee/test` elements, *independent* of what the current value of `$item1` is.

To get what you need you might try this:

```
for $item1 in $db/employees/employee,
return ($item1/mgr,$item1/ename,
    for $item2 in $item1/test
    return $item2/sub1)
```

or, shorter:

```
$db/employees/employee/(mgr, ename, test/sub1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried for your suggestion and it does work.  However I couldn't get the short version working even without the sub element in the XQuery syntax.  Does the following looks correct to you?

`let $db := db:open("example")`
`for $item1 in $db/employees/employee/(mgr, ename)`
`return ($item1/mgr,$item1/ename)`

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.  The correct syntax is `let $db := db:open("example")
for $item1 in $db/employees/employee/(mgr, ename, test/sub1)
return $item1`  Thanks!

Comment: @beyonddc `$db/employees/employee/(mgr, ename, test/sub1)` is also a valid XQuery expression, as CiaPan has shown you. It does exactly the same as `for $item1 in $db/employees/employee/(mgr, ename, test/sub1) return $item1`.

Comment: Possibly the problem with my expressionis is an XPath version? The [XPath tester site](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) does that properly when I choose XPath 2.0, but for 1.0 it says "A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token." as if it didn't understand the sequence construction within a path expression...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Before returning, check with an `if` statement whether `test/sub1` exists or not.

I slightly changed the for clause as well, removing the `db:open()` function, but it's easy to add it back in.

```
for $employee in /employees/employee
return
if ($employee/test/sub1)
then
($employee/mgr, $employee/ename, $employee/test/sub1)
else
($employee/mgr, $employee/ename)
```

and the result will be

```
<mgr/>
<ename>KING</ename>
<mgr>7839</mgr>
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<sub1>one</sub1>
```

---

> You said there is more than one ways to do this, can you please describe further

A slightly different approach would be to use an `if/then/else` XPath expression and unconditionally returning this expression:

```
for $employee in /employees/employee
return
($employee/mgr, $employee/ename, if ($employee/test/sub1) then $employee/test/sub1 else '')
```

And the answer by CiaPan shows yet another way, this time by nesting `for` clauses. In my opinion, it is a little less straightforward but it works nevertheless. CiaPan also shows how a single XPath expression can potentially solve the problem - which is very straightforward!

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works for the use case I described above.  You said there is more than one ways to do this, can you please describe further or point me to certain terminologies that I could do more research on it?

In my application, the xquery statement would be generated base on the element that is begin dragged from a tree view of the XML schema to a table.  I can see that those if statements would start to add up when multiple sub elements are begin dragged to my table.  The end result of the application is to display the XML data in a table format.

Comment: @beyonddc Please see the edit to my answer. I do not see the connection between items being dragged to a table and selecting elements from the input XML. You would need to edit your question and include all the information that is necessary to understand that.

Comment: The xquery statement is actually auto generated by my application.  The issue I am having is the structure of the xquery statement but not the application itself therefore I didn't include the detailed information about my application here.